# How to create MapView that displays markers at several locations on a map?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

How to create MapView that displays markers at several locations on a map, and each marker should have thumbnail, title and subtitle. If this is possible, please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is adding annotations. To do this you'll probably need to create an object (or use an existing one) that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol.

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW26) for more details.